# prove by induction that $(6\,/\,7^n)-1, \forall n \geq 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm trying resolve this exercise but I cannot resolve. Can you help me?
Follow the question.

**Prove by induction that:** $(6\,/\,7^n)-1, \forall n \geq 1$

Thanks!

Edit:

The question was wrong.

About this question, I dont know start with this problem. I'm newbie in discrete.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your thoughts on the problem in the post (what have you tried? where did you get stuck? so that we know better what are your difficulties with the problem). Also use `|` or `\mid` for $a \mid b$ expressions.

Comment: with modular arithmetic, it's obvious, since $7\equiv1\pmod6$; also $7^n-1=(7-1)(7^{n-1}+7^{n-2}+\cdots+7^2+7+1)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $7^{k+1}-1 = 7\times 7^k-1=6\times 7^k + 7^k - 1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

For the inductive step, take $7^{n+1}-1 = 7(7^n)-1$

Now add a "clever form of $0$"